# on clause at end of sql statement

Tags: sql-server

Sorry, I had no idea what to label this question.

In the query below, what does `ON USERDATA` mean?  I'm going through exam guide for sql server 70-762.  there are lots of reference to it and no explanation to what it means.

example:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX PreferredName_Include_FullName
ON Application.People ( PreferredName )
INCLUDE (FullName)
ON USERDATA;
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is an optional area and it shows either partition_scheme_name or filegroup_name.

[image]

Ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-index-transact-sql

Answer (score 0):

It selects which partition scheme to create the index on. Take a look at the following link for more information https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-index-transact-sql#arguments

Comment: Actually with a name like `USERDATA` I think that is the filegroup, not the partition scheme. Though the syntax map makes this ambiguous.